# Creating Custom Form Template

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a vb.net project with over 20-30 forms. I want to apply same options for every form like "no border,backcolor,picturebox at left bottom etc.". and it takes much time to do these for ever form. Please tell me a shortcut :)

(I've thinked about creating one form and duplicating it.)

Answer (score 0):

Creating Template Forms using Visual Inheritance
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7038/Creating-Template-Forms-using-Visual-Inheritance

[RESOLVED] Creating a Windows Form template/library?
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?641019-RESOLVED-Creating-a-Windows-Form-template-library&s=1fb7d88423241485b8fff8e50ef97d04
Create your Form with the properties set then
File (Menu) | Export Template

- Note: Links to other posts aren’t advised but there is a lot of content and didn’t want to just copy/paste, these could become dead links in the future mind.

You can create Project Templates and Item Template which can have code files, assets etc already there, it’s how File | New works.